# quantity of white spaces left of a string jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to count the white spaces left of a string with jQuery.

For example:

```
 String: "    Hello how are you? "  will have 4 white spaces at its left!
```

How can i get that with jQuery?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something that's doable with plain old javascript.

```
function countLeftBlanks(arg) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < arg.length && arg[i] === ' ') {
    i++;
  }
  return i;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Using regexp in plain old JavaScript:

```
var spacesOnLeft = myStr.match(/^ */)[0].length
```

No loops involved. :)

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it work but i used the other aproach so for me the answer was the other one. Hope your answer helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

If we're using RegExp, the below might be a better cross-environment solution:

```
var spacesOnLeft = ( myStr.match(/^ */) || [[]] )[0].length;
```

The above stops a TypeError from being thrown in certain environments when the result of `match` is `null`. In the official [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), the `match` method states that:

> If n = 0, then return null.

Despite this, most modern browsers seem to return an array with an empty string in it. In some environments, however, the ECMAScript definition is honoured, and a TypeError will be thrown if attempting to access `matched[0]`. The NodeJS environment is a good example of this.